# How to batch change file creation date to file modified date on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, date-time, timestamp

I have a lot of files which have their timestamps messed up. Particularly, file modified timestamp reflects the date the files were actually created, but the file creation timestamp reflects some later date at which the files were either burned to DVDs for backup or copied back from them.

How can I batch replace file creation date and time with file modified date and time? Preferably using command line operations, power shell, vbs scripts, or other native tools, although I'm fine with using third-party software.

The OS is Windows 7.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd first check with PowerShell `gci -file -recurse -ea 0 | ? {$_.CreationTime -lt $_.LastWriteTime}| Select FullName,CreationTime,LastWriteTime` and then d o it `gci -file -r -ea 0| ? {$_.CreationTime -lt $_.LastWriteTime}|%{$_.CreationTime=$_.LastWriteTime}`